# Pandas/Matplotlib - How to sort values in a plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset with columns "Company" and "Outcome".

Company is a company name, Outcome is either success or failure

I have created the following graph with this code. How can I sort this so that the top has the most "Outcomes" (i.e. combined Success and Failure) and it goes down in a descending manner?

The code I used is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'Outcome': ['Success', 'Success', 'Failure', 'Failure', 'Success', 'Failure','Success' ]})

df.groupby(['Company', 'Outcome']).size().unstack().plot(kind = 'barh', stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

Additionally, including `sort_values()` after `size()` does not appear to have any effect, so clearly I am using it wrong. Any advice?

[Bar Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlZFy.png)

Comment: Please add a dummy dataframe. Also, when you use the `sort_values`, what are you sorting on? 'Company'? If so it would do it alphabetically.

Comment: I'm new here - I've just updated the code to a simple example. The dummy dataframe isn't showing up despite being in the code - df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'Outcome': ['Success', 'Success', 'Failure', 'Failure', 'Success', 'Failure','Success' ]})

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, sorting at the point of data will sort from the bottom to the largest, so the y-axis should be in reverse order.

**Added: Need to sort by total value**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
                    'Outcome': ['Success', 'Success', 'Failure', 'Failure', 'Success', 'Failure','Success','Success','Success','Success','Success','Success','Success' ]})

df3 = df2.groupby(['Company', 'Outcome']).size().unstack()
df3['Total'] = df3['Failure'].fillna(0)+ df3['Success']
df3.sort_values('Total', ascending=False, inplace=True)
ax = df3[['Failure','Success']].plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

Comment: This is part of the way there. I've applied to a slightly bigger dataset and it appears to be sorting by the number of Successes first, and then subsequently by the number of Failures. I was hoping to get it to sort by total number of successes + failures. For example, it doesn't show this neatly arranged in terms of total - df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': ['C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'], 'Outcome': ['Success', 'Success', 'Failure', 'Failure', 'Success', 'Failure','Success','Success','Success','Success','Success','Success','Success' ]})

Comment: If you need to sort by total, add a new total column and then sort by total column.

Comment: How do I assign the appropriate values to the Total column?